# Rotate and move the ball from top circle to bottom circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a game using canvas, what I have is a `top circle` and `bottom circle`, and a ball spinning.

Starting from the top circle, the ball spin, whenever the ball reach the bottom of circle the ball move or transite from the first circle and start moving in the second circle.

Now the problem is when the ball move to the second circle, there is a small lag, or a delay that is noticeable how can I overcome that?

Here what I have tried:

**Code Snippet**

(also on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Cod3rMax/pen/YzBQejV) )

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 40;

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }

  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = '#0f0';
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
}

let bigTopCircle = new Circle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 4, 130, '#000000');

let smallTopCircle = new Circle(
  bigTopCircle.x,
  bigTopCircle.y,
  bigTopCircle.radius / 1.3,
  '#0B0F1A',
);

let bigBottomCircle = new Circle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height * 0.63, 130, '#000000');

let smallBottomCircle = new Circle(
  bigBottomCircle.x,
  bigBottomCircle.y,
  bigBottomCircle.radius / 1.3,
  '#0B0F1A',
);

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.angle2 = 0;
    this.shouldGoToSecondCircle = false;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
  update() {
    //* this to rotate the ball on the top big circle

    let bx = this.x - bigTopCircle.x;
    let by = this.y - bigTopCircle.y;
    let ballPosition = Math.atan2(by, bx);

    // here check if the ball is in the bottom part of top circle
    if (ballPosition > Math.PI / 2 || this.shouldGoToSecondCircle) {
      // if yes start rotating the ball on the bottom part
      this.shouldGoToSecondCircle = true;
      let newCenterX = bigBottomCircle.x;
      let newCenterY = bigBottomCircle.y;
      let newRadiusDiff = (bigBottomCircle.radius + smallBottomCircle.radius) / 2;
      this.x = newCenterX + newRadiusDiff * Math.cos(-Math.PI / 2 + this.angle2);
      this.y = newCenterY + newRadiusDiff * Math.sin(-Math.PI / 2 + this.angle2);
      this.angle2 -= 0.01;

      console.log(ballPosition);
    }

    // here if the ball is not on the bottom part rotate in top circle
    if (!this.shouldGoToSecondCircle) {
      let centerX = bigTopCircle.x;
      let centerY = bigTopCircle.y;
      let radiusDiff = (bigTopCircle.radius + smallTopCircle.radius) / 2;
      this.x = centerX + radiusDiff * Math.cos(this.angle);
      this.y = centerY + radiusDiff * Math.sin(this.angle);
      this.angle += 0.01;
    }
  }
}

let ball = new Ball(bigTopCircle.x, bigTopCircle.y);

function animate() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ball.update();
  bigTopCircle.draw();
  bigBottomCircle.draw();
  smallBottomCircle.draw();
  smallTopCircle.draw();
  ball.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```css
* {
     background-color: #0b0f1a;
}

canvas {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #0b0f1a;
     border: 1px solid red;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px green;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: the delay isn't noticeable at all. but if it is to you, try adding the `delta` (0.01) before deciding if it needs to switch circle. like, if `x >= target - delta`